# DbContext and scoped dependency

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, simple-injector

I have a simple `DbContext` looking like:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IUserContext _userContext;

    public MyDbContext(IUserContext userContext) : base("DefaultConnectionString")
    {
        _userContext = userContext;

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Configuration>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ... Here I need to creates some filters using the IUserContext dependency

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

This `DbContext` is wired using `Func<T>` factory, [using the guidelines in the Simple Injector documentation](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html): `container.RegisterFuncFactory<DbContext, MyDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);`

```
public static void RegisterFuncFactory<TService, TImpl>(
    this Container container, Lifestyle lifestyle = null)
    where TService : class
    where TImpl : class, TService
{
    lifestyle = lifestyle ?? Lifestyle.Transient;
    var producer = lifestyle.CreateProducer<TService, TImpl>(container);
    container.RegisterSingleton<Func<TService>>(producer.GetInstance);
}
```

But apperently, such simple case is not possible with the `DbContext` because of this message:

> The target context 'MyDbContext' is not constructible. Add a default
>   constructor or provide an implementation of IDbContextFactory.

I dont really like the idea of the  `IDbContextFactory`, so the only solution I can come up with is to remove the dependency on the `MyDbContext`, set it as a property, modify the `RegisterFuncFactory` method and manually initialize the context:

```
internal static void RegisterFuncFactory<TService, TImpl>(this Container container, Func<TImpl> instanceProducer, Lifestyle lifestyle = null) where TService : class where TImpl : class, TService
{
    lifestyle = lifestyle ?? Lifestyle.Transient;
    var producer = lifestyle.CreateProducer<TService>(instanceProducer, container);
    container.Register<Func<TService>>(() => producer.GetInstance, Lifestyle.Singleton);
}

container.RegisterFuncFactory<DbContext, MyDbContext>(() => new MyDbContext
{
    UserContext = container.GetInstance<IUserContext>()
}, Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

While not elegant it works, but is there another and "better" way of doing what I need? I like the explicitly of the dependency on the context, but seem not possible.

**UPDATE**

The error is coming from:

> 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

On this code the return statement of the Query method here:

```
internal sealed class EntityFrameworkRepository<TEntity> : IEntityWriter<TEntity>, IEntityReader<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
    private readonly Func<DbContext> _contextProvider;

    public EntityFrameworkRepository(Func<DbContext> contextProvider)
    {
        _contextProvider = contextProvider;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Query()
    {
        var context = _contextProvider();
        return context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
    }

    // Methods removed for brevity

}
```

Comment: Who is giving you this message? EF migrations?

Comment: Yes, the error is coming from `'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigrationsException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code` during the return statemenet here:  `var context = _contextProvider(); return context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();`

Comment: @janhartmann What is `Entity` (the constraint)? I think you should specify a `class` constraint too, because now `TEntity` could be an interface which isn't allowed

Comment: The Entity is just an abstract class defining an entity in my application, but yes -maybe it should be more specific. :-)

Comment: Post the *full* exception, ie the result of `Exception.ToString()`. This includes any inner exceptions and the call stack of the method that threw the exception. The current error message simply says "Some other problem occured, check inside for details"

Comment: Done, there is no inner exception. And not really any more to the exception. I suspect it has something to do with the migrations that can not initialize the context if there is parameters in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second (default) constructor. This way EF migrations can use this constructor when run from the command line, while you can let your application use the second constructor.

You loose Simple Injector's auto-wiring capabilities on your `DbContext` when you add this second constructor, but this shouldn't be a problem; you can simply wire your context as follows:

```
IUserContext userContext = new AspNetUserContext();

container.RegisterSingleton<IUserContext>(userContext);

var contextProducer = Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateProducer<DbContext>(
    () => new MyDbContext(userContext),
    container);

container.RegisterSingleton<Func<DbContext>>(contextProducer.GetInstance);
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, going to try this. I had to change the singleton registration for compliation to: `container.RegisterSingleton<Func<DbContext>>(() => contextProducer.GetInstance);`

Comment: Worked like a charm! I'll mark your answer as the solution and I'll post an answer of the complete solution for others (or is this not allowed?).

Comment: @janhartmann: I think posting the complete solution is a great practice. More people should do that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only to display for further users what I ended up with. @Steven answer is the right answer.

In order to be able to inject dependencies into the the `DbContext` while supporting migrations, we have to use two constructors. One for the migrations and one for the application.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IUserContext _userContext;

    // For migrations
    public MyDbContext() : base("DefaultConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Configuration>());
    }

    // For applications
    public MyDbContext(IUserContext userContext) : base("DefaultConnectionString")
    {
        _userContext = userContext; 
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ... Code removed for brevity

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

This is then wired in the composition root like:

```
public static void RegisterEntityFramework<TContext>(this Container container, Func<TContext> context) where TContext : DbContext
{
    if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));

    var contextProducer = Lifestyle.Scoped.CreateProducer<DbContext>(context, container);
    container.RegisterSingleton<Func<DbContext>>(() => contextProducer.GetInstance);
}

var userContext = new AspNetHttpUserContext();
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();
container.RegisterSingleton<IUserContext>(userContext);
container.RegisterEntityFramework(() => new WayFinderDbContext(userContext));
container.Verify();
```